Copy to clipboard some previous lines of bash terminal with keyboard only
Let's say you do ls -al in a Bash shell in Debian or Ubuntu and get:
drwxrwxrwt  95 root root 12288 Sep 28  2024 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Sep 28  2024 usr     <-- how to copy this to clipboard?
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Sep 28  2024 var
root@abc:/#

How can I select and copy to clipboard the output, for example, of the (n-2)th line, so that I can paste it later with CTRL+SHIFT+V?
(without using the mouse, everything with keyboard only)
Is it possible with arrow keys and a combination of keys?
Note:

I don't want to use ls -al | any_tool_to_parse_output, but rather the ability to move in previous output lines and copy/paste. One of the reasons is that, often, you don't know in advance that you want to copy the (n-2)th line when running a command: it's only when seeing the output after the command has been run, that you want to copy/paste something.

Let's say we use "Xfce 4 terminal emulator" (/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal), or Gnome Terminal. A solution with one of them would be great.



Then, in general, no.  Not on a standard terminal emulator.  You might be able to find one that has cursor movement, but I've never seen one.  In case you change your mind: ls -al | head -2 | sed -n '2,$p' | xclip -i

I googled "linux emulating mouse movement with keyboard" and see a few results, maybe start there.

Not sure if suits you, but you can use (neo)vim. Example: 1- Open neovim, execute :r!ls -al. 2- Select the part you are interested with vim motions. 3- Use the system register to copy with "+y. All this implies that you have knowledge of vim, and may need some extra conf/install to make it work.

Interesting but I don't know vim. Or maybe I know vim and I don't know vim at the same time @schrodingerscatcuriosity ;)

"in a Bash terminal" – Bash is not a terminal, it is a shell. To copy output that has already got to your terminal, you need help from the terminal (terminal emulator). A terminal multiplexer may be handy. I think tmux can do what you want, out of the box, using its internal buffers (and it has other useful features, example). Integration with an external clipboard is possible. Will you consider using tmux? If yes, do you need support for external clipboard? If yes, should it be for X or Wayland?

@KamilMaciorowski You're right. Let's say we use "Xfce 4 terminal emulator" (/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal), or Gnome Terminal. About tmux: if possible, I'd like to avoid having to run inside tmux to have this feature. I hope this is possible :)

@Basj: if you don't want to use tmux or GNU screen it can only be achieved by your terminal emulator built-in feature

... or a lot of coding needed to duplicate the behavior of tmux or screen

In Linux Mint \w Mate desktop environment on a laptop, I was able to do this by enabling Mouse Keys in the keyboard preferences. Then, the keypad keys could be used to move the mouse pointer. Of course, this will only work if your laptop has a keypad, either physical or by using particular keys via a function key. Assuming you're using a mainstream DE, Mouse Keys or a similar accessibility feature should be available on both Debian and Ubuntu.
The use of a laptop is significant in that holding down the left mouse button is required to do the selection. A laptop ordinarily has mouse buttons accompanying a touchpad that, being on the same surface as the keyboard, are essentially part of the keyboard. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to do a left mouse click on a standard desktop keyboard. Maybe a keyboard shortcut of some sort would work, but I don't know.


How can I select and copy to clipboard the output, for example, of the (n-2)th line, so that I can paste it later with CTRL+SHIFT+V?
(without using the mouse, everything with keyboard only)

You could use fzf and xclip something like
ls -la | fzf | xclip -selection clipboard


Some utility/program send the output to stderr it  might need an additional redirect.
my_command 2>&1 | fzf | xclip -selection clipboard



On a mac replace xclip with pbcopy

for wayland user use wl-copy




Is it possible with arrow keys and a combination of keys?

Write a function , e.g.
my_funct(){ ls -la | fzf --height 40% --reverse | xclip -selection clipboard ; }


bind it to a combination key e.g.
bind -x '"\C-k": my_funct'


Call the function via: CTRL+k

As per comment suggestion one can use vim and use the stdin flag, e.g.
ls -la | vim -

But that requires you to know how to use vim and configure/enable the clipboard feature.

Thanks for answering, but this does not really answer the question, see the "Note" at the end.

To my defense, fzf does not parse the output. but if this answer does not meet your requirement I would gladly delete it.

Please don't delete it @Jetchisel, I'm sure it can still come handy one day for other purposes and/or for other people. Thanks for your answer!
